# PHP SQL Query - Select All Associated w/ Specific Value?

Tags: php, sql, select

I could use some assistance with an sql query. I have a small 3 column table, id, ip, and birthday. id auto increments.

I'm trying to select all birthdays that are associated with a specific ip, but I'm not sure if the SQL statement I wrote is correct. If someone could check this for me it would be appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT birthday, COUNT(ip) FROM $table Group By ip HAVING ( COUNT(ip) > 1) WHERE ip=$ip";
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I would be surprised if you're allowed to parameterize the table name like you're doing.  If you are using ip in the WHERE clause to restrict results to a single ip, then you don't need to Group By ip.   However, if you want to return birthday, then you DO need to group by birthday.

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks I did change group by to birthday, and PHP does all that for tables.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the birthdays with a specific IP you'd simply query:

```
SELECT birthday FROM table WHERE ip="desired value here"
```

If you're trying to count that information, then you could use:

```
SELECT ip, count(*) as `Total` FROM table WHERE id="desired value here" GROUP BY ip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select birthday from $table where ip='<ip goes here>'
```

Be sure to properly escape your inputs. PDO or MySQLi prepared statements are advisable.